# What's wrong with maths script?

Tags: python, scripting, syntax-error

Sorry if this is a beginner mistake but... I'm a beginner. Here's the script:

```
num1 = input("Num1:");
num2 = input("Num2:");

try:
  val = int(num1)
except ValueError:
   print("ERROR : Num1 is not a number!")

   val2 = inf(num2)
   except ValueError:
     print("ERROR : Num2 is not a number!")
print("Maths");
print(num1 + num2);
```

What the script is meant to do is add the two numbers and if they typed in something which isn't a number it says it's not a number.
I keep getting errors but I don't know why. NOTE: this is Python.

This is the error I got:

> ```
> File "<string>", line 10
> except ValueError:
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: You are adding the strings, not the numbers. Also, where is the second `try` statement? I suggest pasting your actual code, instead of re-typing it, so it has no spelling- or indentation-errors or missing parts.

Comment: @tobias_k super new to programming, I have no idea what a second try statement is.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, as @tobias_k states your code is invalid as there is no second `try` statement.

Comment: also, you may want to bear in mind that this won't ever handle floats.  You can cast an int string as a float, but not a float string as an int.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I tried with a couple of code editors, on said that value error was invalid syntax and one said that val had something missing or something. I can't remember the exact error and I can't check right now

Comment: Yes, its saying you have invalid syntax, because your code is all wrong.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr that's why I'm looking for help. Because I can't look this up because no one will have the same problem so I came here hoping someone could help

Comment: Your IDE will tell you the exact line and character the syntax error is occuring at. If you look up the python documentation for how to write `try/except` blocks you will find out what is wrong.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr this is the error I got File "<string>", line 10     except ValueError:          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you look at what is on line 10?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr yes but I don't know how to fix it. That's the reason this question is here

Comment: you have a typo on `val2 = inf(num2)`

Answer (score 3):

programming is all about breaking a (bigger) problem into smaller problems

the first smaller problem you have is to get integer input.  a useful way to do this is abstracting the problem out

```
def get_integer(prompt=""):
    while True:
         try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
         except:
            print "Invalid input. please try again"
```

now you can simply call this method when you want an integer from the user

```
n1 = get_integer("Enter the first integer:")
n2 = get_integer("Enter The second integer:")
```

next you must determine how to add those

```
import operator
def get_operation():
    my_operators = {"+":operator.add,"-":operator.sub}
    while True:
          try:
              return my_operators[raw_input("Enter a + or -:")]
          except KeyError:
              print "Invalid input!"
```

now you can combine the 2 easily

```
 n1 = get_integer("Enter the first integer:")
 n2 = get_integer("Enter The second integer:")
 print get_operation()(n1,n2)
```

you should see something like

```
>>> n1 = get_integer("Enter the first integer:")
Enter the first integer:7
>>> n2 = get_integer("Enter The second integer:")
Enter The second integer:8
>>> print get_operation()(n1,n2)
Enter a + or -:+
15
```

Comment: Why would you reward such a low-effort question with an answer?

Comment: because I am far too nice

Comment: Can someone please explain what I did wrong with the question. It's really bugging me that no one is pointing it out

Comment: @Chickenator if this answer hasn't answered your question why did you accept it? I've put an explanation of your SyntaxError below.

Comment: @Chickenator you did lots wrong ... your indentation is broken ... you have syntax errors ... this is more of a learn2code answer ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley do you want me to just delete the question? Because all I'm getting right now is answers I don't understand, down votes and if you're right then I'm not getting an answer any time soon. Who would of thought it would be so hard to add 2 numbers.

Comment: its not `print 5 + 3`

Comment: Can you at least just tell me what I did wrong with the question? Because that could be useful for the future

Comment: its been covered ... you cannot have an `except` without  a `try` ... and you must have proper indentation you can run `python -tt my_script.py` and it will help you find indentaiton erros

Comment: Im not sure why the question got so many downvotes ... I didnt downvote it ... but there is an appearance of lack of effort ... also this looks like homework, and the answers almost certainly were covered in class at some point

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error you are is a fundamental misunderstanding of how [`try/except` blocks work in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```
num1 = input("Num1:");
num2 = input("Num2:");
try:
  val = int(num1)
except ValueError:
   print("ERROR : Num1 is not a number!")

   val2 = inf(num2)
   except ValueError:
     print("ERROR : Num2 is not a number!")
print("Maths");
print(num1 + num2);
```

Your error points to line 10:

```
   except ValueError:
```

An except block that has no corresponding `try` block. An `except` 'catches' errors that occur within a `try` block, so since there is no `try` for this `except` it is a "Syntax Error", which prevents the code from running.

You can correct it by adding a `try` around where you cast `val2` as an integer like so:

```
try:
    val2 = inf(num2)
except ValueError:
    print("ERROR : Num2 is not a number!")
```

Of important note, this will not fix your code, as as people have stated `inf` is a function that isn't declared, and needs to be:

```
try:
    val2 = int(num2)
except ValueError:
    print("ERROR : Num2 is not a number!")
```

Comment: I did it but I got this error:     File "<string>", line 3     num1 = input("Num1:");        ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block    Which I don't really understand, any help?

Comment: it means your indentation is busted

Comment: That error is literally impossible based on the code you posted. The syntax in python is fundamentally tied to indentation so the smallest mistake will break your code.

Comment: @JoranBeasley so I should start the code again differently?

Answer (score -1):

```
num1 = input("Num1:");
num2 = input("Num2:");

try:
  val = int(num1)
except ValueError:
   print("ERROR : Num1 is not a number!")


try:
  val = int(num1)
except ValueError:
   print("ERROR : Num2 is not a number!")

print("Maths")
print(num1 + num2)
```

What kind of errors were you getting ?
Be sure to checkout python's syntax

Comment: My error is: File "<string>", line 10     except ValueError:          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: It means you have a syntax error at line 10 in your script . Go through the python docs and check out the syntax , maybe indentation ???